# What is the Swift iOS purpose of dragging datasource and delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

http://teachyourselfios.com download v9 open FlowerDetail.  Look at story board, look at Master Scene Table View, and remove both Outlets, datasource and delegate.  Everything runs fine without the dragging of datasource and delegate.  Datasource and delegate in MasterViewController is not programmatically set.

What is the swift iOS purpose of dragging datasource and delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the view controller is a `UITableViewController` (or a `UICollectionViewController`), the setting of these outlets is not necessary. And in this case, the `MasterViewController` is a `UITableViewController`.

But sometimes you have a plain old `UIViewController` and manually add a `UITableView` (or `UICollectionView`) to the scene's main `view` (you do this if you have other controls you want to put on the view in addition to the table/collection view), in which case setting these outlets (or doing it programmatically) is critical. So it's important to know how to do this in those cases where it's needed.

Comment: couldn't have said it better myself. It is also possible to change the default datasource and delegate of a UITableViewController's tableview, by dragging the outlet to the intended entity, or programmatically, thats why they are still there for a UITableViewController's tableview.